# How do I loop through te below given variable in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create vnets for multiple environments using one single variable. I am not quite sure if it is possible. My variable is given below

```
azure_vnets = {
  Prod = [
    {
      cidr = "10.10.0.0/24"
      vnet_name = "prod-vnet1"
      dns  = "10.10.0.1"
      rg   = "prodrg1"
      location = "eastus"
    },
    { 
      cidr = "10.10.1.0/24"
      vnet_name = "prod-vnet2"
      dns  = "10.10.0.2"
      rg   = "prodrg2"
      location = "eastus"
    }     
  ],
  nonProd = [
     {
      cidr = "10.10.0.0/24"
      vnet_name = "nonprod-vnet1"
      dns  = "10.10.0.1"
      rg   = "nonprodrg1"
      location = "eastus"
    },
    { 
      cidr = "10.10.1.0/24"
      vnet_name = "nonprod-vnet2"
      dns  = "10.10.0.2"
      rg   = "nonprodrg2"
      location = "eastus"
    }    
  ]
}
```

So as to create multiple vnets from this

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "this" {
for_each = xxx
name = each.xxx
xxxx
xxx
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **flatten** it first:

```
locals {
  flat_azure_vnets = merge([
      for env_name, env_vn_list in var.azure_vnets:
         {
           for idx, env_vn in env_vn_list:
             "${env_name}-${idx}" => env_vn
         }
    ]...)
}
```

then you use it:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "this" {
  for_each = local.flat_azure_vnets
  name = each.value["vnet_name"]
  xxxx
  xxx
}
```

Comment: Thanks @marcin I tried but I am getting below error. Do you have any idea

Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got
"tuple".

Comment: @Vaishnav My code is correct. If you get any error it means that your variable `azure_vnets` is not what you posted it in the question. Also I hope you did not remove the three dots?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I missing the dots :) . +1. Finally if you have any relative articles explaning the concept of this looping will help me understand the flow. Thank you once again

Comment: @Vaishnav The [three dots](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) change `merge([a,b,c])` into `merge(a,b,c)`.